Using one line in Try in python
I'm studying CS50p and the tutor says it's best practice to have as few lines as possible, ideally one, in a Try, but I really struggle to do this.
How could I write the following code so that I only try the input?
while True:
    try:
        # How to have just 1 line in try??
        order = input("Order: ").title().strip()
        if order in menu:
            price += menu[order]
            print(f"Total: ${price}")
    except (EOFError, KeyError):
        break


Identify which line can throw EOFError, move other ones outside of try. Then do the same with KeyError.

"One line in a try block"? Nonsense

The reason why it's generally a best practice to have as few lines as possible in the body of a try statement is to make sure there is only one possible source that produces the exception being handled so that the logics of the exception handler can be tailored specifically to the nature of the error.
In your case, EOFError can only be raised by the input function, and KeyError can only be raised by a missing key from accessing menu[order], so you can enclose those two specific statements in try statements instead:
while True:
    try:
        order = input("Order: ").title().strip()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if order in menu:
        try:
            price += menu[order]
        except KeyError:
            break
        print(f"Total: ${price}")

But KeyError is unlikely to occur since you already put menu[order] in an if condition of order in menu, so you can remove the if condition to adopt an EAFP code pattern:
while True:
    try:
        order = input("Order: ").title().strip()
    except EOFError:
        break
    try:
        price += menu[order]
    except KeyError:
        break
    print(f"Total: ${price}")


That's great, much clearer on this now. Thanks!

Really helpful answer !! (+1)

you can remove the price increment logic from the try-except block as follow. The try block only contains the input function call that might raise an EOFError. The rest of the code is outside the try-except structure.
order = None
while True:
    try:
        # How to have just 1 line in try??
        order = input("Order: ").title().strip()
    except EOFError:
        break

    if order in menu:
        price += menu[order]
        print(f"Total: ${price}")

Please note that the KeyError exception is removed from the except clause because it would not be raised by the input function. However, if you're concerned about a KeyError when accessing menu[order], you could use a get method instead, which returns None if the key is not found in the dictionary:
while True:
    try:
        order = input("Order: ").title().strip()
    except EOFError:
        break

    price_increment = menu.get(order)
    if price_increment is not None:
        price += price_increment
        print(f"Total: ${price}")


idk how to write print() function using one line, but two line is possible for this case
while True:
    try:
        price += menu[input("Order: ").title().strip()]
        print(f"Total: ${price}")
    except (EOFError, KeyError):
        break


You could write this in one line but it's a ridiculous paradigm and totally contradicts the Zen of Python
while True:
    try:
        print(f"Total: ${price}\n" if (order := input("Order: ").title().strip()) in menu and (price := price + menu[order]) else "", end="")
    except (EOFError, KeyError):
        break


Thanks for your reply. I meant more so that I was catching 1 specific error with the try.
